# Running a systemd service at boot with ALSA

Tags: systemd, audio, services, raspbian

I am trying to launch a python systemd service that uses ALSA sound when the Raspberry Pi boots.

Here is the Talkie.service file in /etc/systemd/system:

```
Description=bondz-client
# Requires=sys-devices-platform-soc-soc:sound-sound-card1-controlC1.device

[Service]
User=user
Group=user
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/romaing/Documents/Talkie_basic_sound_test.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/romaing/Documents/

StandardOutput=append:/var/log/bondz.log
StandardError=append:/var/log/bondz.log

[Install]
WantedBy=sound.target
```

If I start the service manually with `systemctl` it works fine but upon boot I get this error in the logs (and systemd stops)
Here's the log file content :

```
2024-01-14 16:30:23,363 |Player| INFO:Device count =  0... 
2024-01-14 16:30:23,364 |Player| INFO:Playing file tests/myrecording.wav... 
2024-01-14 16:30:23,403 |Player| ERROR:Error playing tests/myrecording.wav 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/romaing/Documents/Talkie_basic_sound_test.py", line 71, in playWaveFile
    playStream = audio.open(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 639, in open
    stream = PyAudio.Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid output device (no default output device)
```

Here's a simplified python code that loops a sound :

```
from Player import Player
import io
import wave
import logging
import traceback
import pyaudio

player = Player()
logger = logging.getLogger("Player")
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s |%(name)s| %(levelname)s:%(message)s", level=logging.INFO
)



def play():
    playWaveFile("tests/myrecording.wav", play)


def playWaveFile(filepath, callback):
    # info = audio.get_default_output_device_info()
    logger.info(f"Device count =  {audio.get_device_count()}... ")
    logger.info(f"Playing file {filepath}... ")
    try:
        wave_file = wave.open(filepath, "rb")

        playStream = audio.open(
            format=audio.get_format_from_width(wave_file.getsampwidth()),
            channels=wave_file.getnchannels(),
            rate=wave_file.getframerate(),
            output=True,
        )
        data = wave_file.readframes(1024)
        while data:
            playStream.write(data)
            data = wave_file.readframes(1024)
        # Cleanup
        playStream.stop_stream()
        playStream.close()
        logger.info(f"Playing {filepath} done.")
        callback()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error playing {filepath} ")
        traceback.print_exc()
        # self._statusManager.set_app_status(Status.ERROR)


play()
```

I guess the sound card isn't loaded when the service start but I thought sound.target would solve it, which it does not...
Being a beginner on this topic, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am running on Raspbian 11 (bullseye).

Here is the output of `aplay -l` :

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: vc4hdmi [vc4-hdmi], device 0: MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0 [MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: seeed2micvoicec [seeed-2mic-voicecard], device 0: bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0 [bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Card 1 is the one I need to use.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is expected that you can't "hold" / "delay" a service start with `After=sound.target` since `sound.target` does not exist in the "bootup unit tree".

systemd (can) only order a unit against another if they are in the tree, i.e., it is *deterministically* defined to be pulled in (by some other unit that is also defined so) at certain point during the bootup process.

`sound.target` is not such a case. When and whether it will be started at all completely [depends on when and whether a sound card shows up](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v254/rules.d/99-systemd.rules.in#L57) (i.e., is detected / enumerated). To state the obvious, systemd does not (at least not necessarily) know whether there will be a sound card device unit when it starts its bootup process.

Yet an "invalid" ordering does NOT prevent a unit to be pulled in (by some other unit, like in this case, `multi-user.target`).

---

The probably-only correct way to make sure a unit/service starts after a sound card shows up is to make it (only) `WantedBy=sound.target`. Make sure you perform a disable-enable cycle after making the change under the `[Install]` section of the file, otherwise it won't be in effect.

Because by the time systemd "begins to" start the target, the sound card is already available, so you shouldn't need `After=sound.target` at all. (*Hopefully* having it would be harmless in usual cases. However, the ordering mechanism is IMHO somewhat fragile. I'd strongly advice NOT to have an ordering unless you confirm that it is actually necessary.)

---

Note that since `sound.target` will be pulled in once *a* (i.e., any) sound card shows up. Therefore, if you need to make sure that a specific sound card is available by the time your own unit/service gets started, `sound.target` will not suits you unless it is known that you desire card practically always shows up first.

In such a scenario, you might need to resort to a udev rule that is similar to what gets the `sound.target` pulled in, in which you can match with e.g. `ENV{ID_PATH}`.

---

Note that in many distro, non-root users that are not in the `audio` group do not have access to sound devices. You may check the actual ownership / permissions with `ls -l /dev/snd/`.

However, systemd has some kind of "trick for norms / user-friendliness" called `uaccess` ([a](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v254/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules.in#L30), [b](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v254/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules.in#L17)), which will dynamically add an ACL on the dev nodes of the sound devices for user that has logged in. (It's probably more complicated than that but I'm not familiar with all the session and seat stuff, and the details are irrelevant to the OP.)

Since you have something like:

```
User=my-username
Group=
```

in your service file, the sound devices may not be accessible by the process if `my-username` is not in the `audio` group, not until you have logged in with that user. (Or maybe even if it is; I haven't really checked what `Group=(empty)` does.)

So make sure `my-username` have permission (`rw`?) to `/dev/snd/*`. Add it to the `audio` group, and/or set `Group=` or `SupplementaryGroups=` to `audio`. Whatever that works and is right for you.

Also don't assume `audio` group is a thing in your system / distro. Check first.

Comment: Eventually I tracked the name of the card `systemctl -l |grep sound-card` added it `Requires=`and the `After=` and it worked. Not sure if I need the two statements but it worked. :)

Comment: @16ar Yeah you can ask it to wait for a device unit instead, but you might be blocked for a timeout if the sound card is gone. (I don't remember exactly whether that is true though, and assuming it's an internal sound card, the chance for it to happen would be slim anyway.)

Comment: For an unknown reason I have been misleading in my previous comment stating that it worked, because it does not. I carefully read again your comprehensive answer and it seems  like the sound card isn't mounted unless I login (service log shows "0" when i print ```pyaudio.get_device_count()```). The user is in the audio group. I modify the question so it is more accurate to what I am having right now

Answer (score 1):

I think your dependency on `sound.target` is correct (although I would also add `Requires=sound.target`, since it does require sound support). I'm not entirely sure what the problem is here -- maybe some ALSA component takes a moment to settle -- but there are some simple ways to work around it.

### Allow your service to restart automatically

Instead of manually restarting the service, configure it to restart automatically in the event of a failure:

```
Description=My Talkie App
After=network.target sound.target

[Service]
User=my-username
Group=
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/romaing/Documents/Talkie.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This will try to restart every 5 seconds on failure.

### Wait for the sound device with an ExecStartPre action

Alternately, you can have your service block until the desired audio device is available. Something like:

```
Description=My Talkie App
After=network.target sound.target

[Service]
User=my-username
Group=
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/timeout 300 /bin/sh -c 'while ! amixer -D sysdefault:CARD=USB > /dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/romaing/Documents/Talkie.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This will wait up to 5 minutes for the card identified by `sysdefault:CARD=USB` to be available.

Comment: No, neither `After=` nor `Requires=`/`Wants=` is the correct way to make use of `sound.target`. The target is pulled in a transient manner through a udev rule if and when a sound card shows up (think of it as a `systemctl start` at some random point), so ordering against it essentially makes no sense, let alone pulling it. The correct way is make your service wanted by it. (Also, AFAICT one shouldn't make use of it if there are multiple sound card. There's also the ACL systemd trick that matters because somehow the OP decided not to use root for the command.)